# Entity Framwork 6.0 AcceptAllChanges() missing

Tags: entity-framework-6

I saw the error below when trying to call the AcceptAllChanges() in "using"

> "Entity" does not contain a definition for 'AcceptAllChanges' and no extension method 'AcceptAllChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'Entity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 using (vbfEntity)
        {
            vbfEntity.Database.Connection.Open();

            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                //Operation code
            }

            if (src.status)
                vbfEntity.AcceptAllChanges();
        }
```

Can anybody help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[AcceptAllChanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.acceptallchanges.aspx) is a method from the older `ObjectContext` API.

For EF6 and DBContext API use `SaveChanges()` or add this

```
   ObjectContext obj = new ObjectContext("connstring");
   obj.AcceptAllChanges();
```